# How to plot PCA features which are in vector format using pyspark?

Tags: plot, pyspark, lambda, pca, attributeerror

[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yj8fx.png)

Above is my dataframe, after performing PCA to my features:
I want to plot the PCA features (i.e. values ) with hue as Article, **in Pyspark**

I tried the following code,

```
def abc(x):
    lst = x['values']
    return lst[0], lst[1], lst[2]

pca_df['col1'], pca_df['col2'], pca_df['col3'] = pca_df.map(lambda x: abc(x.select('PCA_features')))
```

I am getting the below error:

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'

Can someone help me in extracting the features in columns like feature1, feature2, feature3, in the dataframe along with the articles, so that I can plot it.
Or suggest if there is some other way to do the same.

Comment: Could you show the schema of your dataframe?

Comment: @JonathanLam,  ``article: string(nullable = True), PCA_features: vector(nullable= True)``

Comment: @JonathanLam, yes the above link helped me to access element of Vector , but still I am not able to plot it. ``pca_df = df.withColumn('PC_1',ith("pca",lit(0))).withColumn('PC_2',ith("pca",lit(1)))``                          ``sns.scatterplot(data = pca_df, x='PC_1', y='PC_2', hue = 'article')
plt.title('PCA Features')
plt.show()``     It is giving error {ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.}

Comment: what type is `pca_df`? If that is a `spark-df ` or `pandas-df` there is no map function available.